# Python Using AND logic on two binary numbers to produce a new binary number

Tags: python

I'm trying to use an AND function to produce a new binary number from two other binary numbers. However, I keep getting 000000000000 as the output. Could anyone spot where I’m going wrong in my code?

```
def andop(x,y):
 if x == 1 and y == 1:
       return 1
 else:
       return 0

v =  input("Enter IP address: ")
ip = v.split(".")
b1 = format(int(ip[0]),'08b')
x =  input("Enter submask address: ")
subm = x.split(".")
bi1 = format(int(subm[0]),'08b')

for x in b1:
 for y in bi1:
   print(andop(x,y),end = '')
```

Comment: python has standard module [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)

Comment: you should rather use `for x,y in zip(b1,bi1): print(andop(x,y), end='')`

Comment: Rather than implementing it yourself, you might have an easier time using the built-in binary "and" operator, `&`. Works on integers out-of-the-box, no iterating over digits required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing a string to a number. Alter the final line to e.g:

```
print(andop(int(x),int(y)),end = '')
```

Also, note that the binary "and" operation is a built-in. You could have easily re-written this program in a much clearer fashion:

```
v =  input("Enter IP address: ")
ip = v.split(".")
b1 = int(ip[0])
x =  input("Enter submask address: ")
subm = x.split(".")
bi1 = int(subm[0])

print(format(b1 & bi1, 'b'))
```

Finally, to work with IP addresses, there's an `ipaddress` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html.

Comment: I think you made small typo - it should be `subm[0]` instead of `ip[1]` in `bi1 = int(ip[1])`